# What is the deciability of randomness?

Tags: random

Let `f(n)` be a function that returns `1` iff `n` consecutive `1`s are found in an infinite random binary string.

What is the decidability of this function?

This is not a homework question, but my peers and I did think of it while doing reduction and decidability questions :)

Comment: I couldn't add the tags "decidability" or "reduction" without 1000 rep :(

Comment: Is the string given along with $n$?

Comment: See my edit (stating it's infinite). If it's infinite, does it matter whether it's given?

Comment: The thing is there is no such thing as a "random" sequence. Sequences, in themselves, are neither random nor non-random. It is the process with which they are obtained that is random or not. What I am saying is basically that $f$ is, at the moment, not well defined, thus its decidability cannot yet be discussed